# Crear un programa de multi-opciones

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Hola soy nuevo en este mundo de la programación y el profesor me pide,
realiza un programa que al comenzar le pida al usuario que seleccione una de 4 opciones:

Convertir de bolívares a dólares,
Convertir de dólares a bolívares,
Buscar empleado y
Calcular promedio de calificaciones

Las ultimas dos opciones es donde encuentro el problema, en el caso de agregar los empleados al omento de buscarlos me dice usuario no encontrado así el nombre este en el array... Ahora al momento de promediar las notas no se que hacer en este caso, por favor si alguien me ayuda.

```
var opt;
    opt = parseInt( prompt( 'Menu de Opciones: \n\t1. Convertir de Bolívares a Dólares \n\t2. Convertir de Dólares a Bolívares\n\t3. Buscar empleado \n\t4. Calcular promedio de calificaciones \n\n Por Favor Ingresa una opcion: ') );

    //Opcion 1
    function cambioDeBolivaresADolares(){
                    const tasaDeCambioActual = prompt('Ingresa la tasa de cambio del Dólar\n\n. Ejemplo: 400000.00') ,
                    bolivares = prompt('Ingresa la cantidad de bolívares a cambiar') ;

                    const resultado = bolivares / tasaDeCambioActual;
                
                    document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'La Cantidad de bolívares equivalentes es: ' + resultado.toFixed(2);
                }
    //Opcion 2
                function cambioDeDolaresABolivares(){
                    const tasaDeCambioActual = prompt('Ingresa la tasa de cambio del Dólar\n\n. Ejemplo: 400000.00') ,
                    dolares = prompt('Ingresa la cantidad de dólares a cambiar') ;

                    const resultado = dolares * tasaDeCambioActual;

                    document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'La Cantidad de bolívares equivalentes es: ' + resultado.toLocaleString();
                }
    //opcion 3 agregar empleado
                let misEmpleados = [];
                var empleados = document.getElementById('result');

                class Empleado{
                    constructor(nombre){
                        this.nombre = nombre;
                    }
                }
                function aggEmpleado(){
                    var nombre = prompt('Ingresa el Nombre del empleado a agregar');
                    var empleado = new Empleado(nombre);
                    misEmpleados.push(empleado);
                    actualizarEmpleados();
                }
                function actualizarEmpleados() {

                    empleados.innerHTML = ''; 

                    for (var i = 0; i < misEmpleados.length; i++) {

                        empleados.innerHTML = empleados.innerHTML +
                            '<p>' +
                                '<p>' + misEmpleados[i].nombre + '</p>' +
                            '</p>';
                    }
                }

                function repetir() {
                    for(var i = 0; i <5; i++){
                        aggEmpleado();
                    }
                }
        //opcion 3 buscar empleado
                var encontrado = -1,
                sr;

                function buscarEmpleado() {
                    sr = prompt('Ingresa el nombre del Empleado a Buscar');

                    for(buscador = 0; buscador < misEmpleados.length; buscador++){
                        if( misEmpleados[buscador] == sr){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(encontrado == -1){
                        alert('Usuario no encontrado!');
                    }else{
                        alert('Encontrado!');
                    }
                }

    //opcion 4
    let misNotas = []; 
    var notas = document.getElementById('result');


    class Notas {
        constructor(notas) {
            this.notas = notas;
        }
    }


    function aggNotas() {
    var  notas = prompt('Ingresa las notas del Alumno');
    var notas = new Notas(notas);
    misNotas.push(notas);
    }

    function repetirN() {
        for(var i = 0; i <10; i++){
            aggNotas();
        }
    }

    const result = 0;
    misNotas.forEach(function promedio(){total += promedio;});

    switch(opt){
        case 1:
                cambioDeBolivaresADolares();
            break;
        case 2:
            cambioDeDolaresABolivares();
            break;
        case 3:
            repetir();
            buscarEmpleado();
            break;
        case 4:
            repetirN();
            promedio();
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Favor ingresar una opcion valida');
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para la opción 3 el problema es que estas buscando si un string es igual a una instancia de un objeto y lo que tienes que comprobar es si la propiedad nombre del "objeto" es igual al string.

```
if( misEmpleados[buscador].nombre == sr){
  break;
}
```

Y en el caso de las notas para el promedio es un error de sintaxis.

```
misNotas.forEach(nota => total += nota.notas);
```